# Command /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7

I do realize that there is one solution to this on StackOverflow. However it did not fix the error for me.

Using Xcode 7 beta 4, Swift 2.0, OS X El Capitan.

Here is a screenshot of my issue: http://imgur.com/ag4emii

How can I get rid of this build error ?

Comment: provide more detail, was it during a library integration?, after you added some lines? after upgrading xcode?

Comment: The error seems to have disappeared.

Comment: @LéonardBonfils How did you get it to disappear?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. I remember trying everything I could think of and somehow it ended up working. Stuff like deleting derived data, making sure that all of my files were properly organized in my Xcode project, deleting and re-adding files, really anything that I could think of...